# Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS Won't Boot w/Monitor Connected

Tags: boot, monitor

I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS on a Lenovo RD540 server.  Actually two of them.  Both servers experience same behavior.

1) Server stalls during bootup.

2) The most recent message during boot is "mei 0000:00:16.0: initialization failed".

3) Bootup stalls ONLY if monitor is connected.  If I disconnect the VGA cable and boot, then connect monitor after I've given it time to boot up, I'm at the login prompt and there is no issue.  If I leave monitor connected it always stalls during boot.

I tried blacklisting mei thinking it was the problem given the error message that always shows when it stalls.  I followed the instructions here: http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Resolve_mei:_Init_hw_failure_or_mei:_initialization_failed

Note the instructions didn't work correctly.  I actually had to do the command "blacklist mei_me" to get MEI to blacklist.  "blacklist mei" didn't do anything.  After blacklisting MEI the problem still exists, the only difference is that the error message (#2) is gone.  But instead the boot still stalls, but there is no discernable error causing the stall.  My current theory is that this issue has nothing to do with MEI and is maybe graphics related?  But I'm really perplexed.  It's a server, terminal only.  Not loading a window manager.  Only stalls on boot if monitor is connected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue, it was graphics related.

I made the following change to /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"